# Put HTML in Javascript source or use AJAX to retrieve the HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My application has message boxes, ones like on Facebook, I made which are working very well but I am starting to dislike the way I implement a certain part of the message boxes.

Every message box has a title bar, a title in that title bar and an optional "X" button to close the box. Each box has a default body(`<p>` element for the message and a close button) each time you create one but you can put any HTML into the body of the box and here is where my uncertainty is.

On my login page if you forgot your password and click on the "Forgot password?" text a message box appears and the body of the box is custom HTML(input field for email address and a submit button) and that HTML is gotten from the Javascript source when I am creating the box.

Example:

```
....
....
var bodyHTML = 'Custom HTML for the body of this box';
var options = {'title': 'Password Recovery', 'bodyHTML': bodyHTML, 'hideBigCloseButton': true, 'removeOnClose': true};
createMessageBox('password-recovery-box', options, callback);
```

By the end of this application I will definitely end up with at least 7 or 8 message boxes where the body of the box has custom HTML, it may only be 10 lines of HTML or it may be 50 and I don't like the idea of having so much HTML scattered around in the source of Javascript files.

I was thinking of maybe using jQuery to send a GET request to a controller in the application (site.com/ajax/load-box-template/recover-password) and that would give me back the HTML for putting in the body of the custom message box?

Is the latter overkill or better than the first way? Both will work but which is the better way? or maybe there is a better way than the two methods I mentioned?

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: You may want to look into [one of the template systems available](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/).

Comment: I definitely wouldn't include that html in the javascript. I would include it directly in the page hidden by css before i did that. A templating system would probably be better. Even requesting it with ajax would be better, as long as you cached the result and didn't request the same template twice.

Comment: I'd keep presentation stuff in the HTML/CSS and pull it from there and make it visible when needed with the JS.

Comment: I am with Pointy on the templates - either in the page or pulled in via ajax.

Comment: Ok thanks I am going to look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the $.load() function to load an external page with the HTML from message box:
You put the HTML in a hidden div after you can use in js:

example:
HTML>

```
<div id="somediv" style="display: none">
```

js>

```
$('#somediv').load('someExternalHTML.html', function() {
    var options = {'title': 'Password Recovery', 'bodyHTML': $('#somediv').html(), 'hideBigCloseButton': true, 'removeOnClose': true};
createMessageBox('password-recovery-box', options, callback);
});
```

Hope this help.

Pablo.